# Can i use the .class files in my bin folder to get back my SRC files?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have no idea what happened while i was coding with EclipseIDE. My laptop froze out of nowhere, i had to force shutdown and when i opened Eclipse again, my SRC folder is gone from my java project folder. I can't find it in recycle bin, can't find it with my search bar and it's just gone. 
However i still have my .class files in the bin folder. I really need my SRC files back as they were to be submitted by today. Can i get them back in any way???
https://image.ibb.co/cOhJXf/Screenshot-5.png

Comment: Right click on the project and select 'Restore from Local History...' and see what Eclipse has in the local history. Decompilers are a last resort and often give poor results.

Comment: Just use version control system like git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many Java Decompiler's available to get the Source code from Byte Code. Here is the one i use

http://jd.benow.ca/

**Cavaj [Java Decompiler]** https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/releases/download/v1.4.0/jd-gui-windows-1.4.0.zip

Comment: You can also use the Java decompilers (of your choice) online : [http://www.javadecompilers.com/](http://www.javadecompilers.com/). You can drag & drop .class, .jar ...

Comment: Note that a decompiler does not yield the original source file back, but an equivalent version. Usually they are less readable and contain some changes, regarding *java magic* (such as default constructors for example).

Comment: Agreed @Zabuza Rather than loosing the complete code. Some recovered code may be helpful at times.